# Android Filesystem (sharing files across apps, via service)

Tags: android, service, android-intent, filesystems, ipc

I'm having a rough time figuring out what would be the best way to do the following:
I'm building a library to be used by different apps. This library provides a user system,
through a service, that is started by a "manager app" (used to log-in, add users, etc.).

I need to provide a facility for sharing files across apps.

Imagine that we have an application called APP XPTO. This APP need to store
some files (it could be voice recordings, for this example). But It should not do so
in its private application space (provided by Android, by default). It should be on a space
that is accessible to the manager app (or the service if you will). Also, these
files need to be encrypted, since I'm providing a multi-user system through the service,
but I don't want to face privacy issues.

I thought of having the service manage this file system (FS) abstraction, by creating 
a class for representing a file:

```
class MyFile { // make it parcelable
    private String fullpath;
    private byte[] data;
    private User user;
}
```

And providing basic FS usage through intents.

APP XPTO could send an intent asking for a file, providing, in the intent, its
path and the username it "belongs" to. The service would look for the file,
decrypt it by using the user key (identified by the username), and create a new
MyFile object to put it in the intent and send it to APP XPTO.

This way the files can be stored in a "private app space", since they will be
served by the service. Right?

This seems a "little bit" odd, however. I know that Android isn't a multi-user
OS (although that is being addressed) and that this idea, alone, goes against at
least one of the Android's security mechanisms (the "private space" for each app),
but I need this to work, this or something similar. It also seems to me that
serving files through intents is somewhate "strange"...

Any observations, or ideas?

Comment: This is the point I'm concerning. I'm using an app and want it to sync data it stores with my friends. It would be nice to have a thirdparty app/service that could make any application to sync via files (if it supports them) as they are. I'm not familiar with intents and data providers yet but I'm thinking of this feature.

Comment: You mean something in the likes of dropbox?

Comment: Yep. During some experiments I did not found the way to upload from android device. I did not ever found the shots directory available to upload camera shots by default.

Answer (score 1):

To share data among different applications on Android use `ContentProvider`

Instead of Service, you will implement a ContentProvider. The users of the data can call the provider through `ContentResolver`

Comment: I thought of using a content provider, but isn't it suited for wrapping databases? I want to be able to store pics, videos, etc. and storing that in a DB might not be a good idea.

Comment: Underlying storage for a Content Provider does not have to be a Database. You can very well use the file system as storage. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#DataStorage

Comment: Well, the thing is, I really need a simple abstraction of a File System, since there is the need to create/store files, besides making them "available".

Continuing with the voice recording example, APP XPTO just finished recording a new voice record, and now it needs to store it in a place where it is accessible to other apps (encrypted with the user key of the user that is currently logged-in in the service run by the "manager app"). This is is the issue. Here, keeping in mind the "intent FS system", I could, perhaps, just create a MyFile object and send it through an intent to the service.

Comment: So the idea is to provide a service to share any piece of data for any app you would have using standart way and underlying implementation of this should be an encripted distributed storage (file system)? I noticed that some apps have a feature to share (e.g. webpage in Chrome can be easyly saved in Evernote). How does it work?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. But what do you mean by saving the page in Evernote? Perhaps you're referring to the usage of intent-filters.